# Не читается штрих-код созданный с помощью шрифта в Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, crystalreport

Делаю проект для учебы и столкнулся с проблемой. Штрих-коды созданные с помощью шрифта не сканируются (проверял пока только с помощью телефона, но подозреваю, что и со сканером тоже ничего не выйдет). Изначально использовал шрифт Free 3 of 9, но потом проверил и со многими другими - результат тот же. Кодирую 13-значные числа. Один штрих-код получилось частично прочитать (почему-то выдало только первые 4 цифры). Подскажет кто-нибудь, в чем может быть проблема? Или я что-то не так делаю?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос, ШКИ такой как на картинке? Если да - шрифт. Не видел ШКИ для Crystal хотя использую его. Вы используете какую-то либу для ШКИ (сталкивался с такой), используйте именно тот шрифт который идет с этой либой.

Comment: Какой у вас тип ШКИ, стандартный EAN-13? Если у вас EAN13 - то должно быть две короткие спереди и две короткие сзади. EAN13 имеет особенность, если вы не соблюдаете контрольную сумму в последнем числе - то сканер читать такой ШКИ не будет (а смартфон прочтет), надо а)генерировать правильную КС, б)генерировать другой тип ШКИ, например code128 в)перепрограммировать сканер на чтение ШКИ без проверки КС.

Comment: Ещё, сканер можно спецом запрограммировать что бы он читал только ШКИ "своего формата", вырезал цифры, добавлял цифры, читал только перых 5 и т п., поэтому если у вас на предприятии действуют какие-то правила на ШКИ - то вам их нужно тоже знать. Если с вас решили поприкаловаться, или если сканер непонятно чей непонятно зачем и т п (телефон ШКИ читает а сканер нет) - то прийдется сбросить сканер.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо за то, что ответили, либы я никакие не использую, только Crystal Reports со шрифтами из инета. 
Со своей проблемой я вроде разобрался, дело скорее всего было в шрифте (либо же в его неправильном использовании, не уверен). 
Воспользовался шрифтом CCode39 и 10-значными кодами, все сканируется на ура (если использовать 11 цифр и больше, то бесполезно, но для меня разницы особой нет). Поэтому вопрос можно считать закрытым.